# create an object with out new keyword in c#

Tags: c#-2.0

```
  public class Animal
    {

        public void Eat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Animal eats for living.");
        }
    }
```

Animal a = new Animal();

is it  really required  to use new  keyowrd when we  instantiate  an object ?

can we  do like  this

Animal a = Animal();

any help here  would  be great.

Comment: This question is immensely weird considering that every programming language follows a more or less strict grammar and "new" is the keyword to call upon a type's constructor method which returns a new instance of a type. What you are doing is calling an Animal method in the scope where a resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can always use [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4wc81dc.aspx) - [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx). Not sure if you would actually find it simpler than new though.

Also looking at your example, you probably want to make it [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as your methods are not acting on a specific instance of your class. That ways you can directly call `Animal.Eat()`.

```
  public static class Animal
  {

        public static void Eat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Animal eats for living.");
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To instantiate an object yes you always need to use new. That being said, if for somereason you don't like that you could create a static load method in your class that contains the new keyword. This doesn't change the fact that you are using new but it does hide it. Something like this:

```
public class Animal
{
    private Animal(){}
    public static Animal Load()
    {
         return new Animal();
    }
    public void Eat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal eats for living.");
    }
}
```

Or you could just make a static class.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your aversion to using "new"?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have C++ in mind, for which there's a difference between instantiating an object with or without new.

This does not apply in C#. "Animal" is always a reference to the object. If the C# syntax allowed to write "Animal a = Animal();", that would likely be meaning exactly the same as "Animal a = new Animal();